# CentOS precess killed

Tags: python, pandas, centos7

My python script(using pandas dataframe) runs as a background process on centos. It is currently started at the command line in a Terminal window (used screen).
After 1 hours later, I opened this Terminal windows as screen, but it was killed.
I used "dmesg" to see kernel log.

[image: Terminal Image (dmesg)]

I am not sure why my python script is killed.
I used "free -m" to see the Mem and Swap.

[image: Termial Image (free -m)]

Please teach me how to solve this issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is the Linux OOM-killer. You should be able to find more information about tuning it at [unix.se].

Comment: Are you running this on a virtual machine?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was running this python script on real server.

Comment: I run this python script again, but after some minutes, it was killed.